# How to check whether any UIBackgroundTask is active through out the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, multitasking, suspend

I am using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` at many places in my app whenever it's necessary to complete a task and I do `endBackgroundTask` when the task is over.
There are some crucial parts of my code where i want to know whether the app currently can suspend (if backgrounded).

So, whenver I do `endBackgroundTask`, I want to check whether any `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` in the entire app is **not** `UIBackgroundTaskInvalid` so that I can notify all the the crucial parts that the app is no longer protected by any  `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and is supendable.
Is there any property of `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` which will store these values? Or any other way to know that?

Comment: Or do I've to maintain a global variable to keep the count of all the background tasks begun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to store the value of this as a property if you want to access it from lower down in your app. If you store it as a property of your app delegate you can access it anywhere by:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] backgroundTask]
```

Comment: yes...so probably storing is the only way to access that information. iOS should provide some mechanism for this.